# jQuery Change Div Button States & Click Disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, frontend

The javascript jQuery code below works, except I would like to add 2 features to the button's state.

1. When a user clicks one of the buttons, the other button that was not clicked gets a new class (look).
2. Both button's state should change to unclickable.

```
[div id="1" class="__button_image"] [/div]
[div id="2" class="__button_image"] [/div]
```

```
$("div.__button_image").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("__button_image_hover");
});

$("div.__button_image").mouseout(function () {
    jq(this).removeClass("__button_image_hover");
});

$("div.__button_image").click(function () { 
    $(this).removeClass("__button_image_hover");
    $(this).addClass("__button_image_clicked");

    jQuery.get('/do/request');        
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is final code I went with:

```
$("div.__button_image").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("__button_image_hover");
});

$("div.__button_image").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("__button_image_hover");
});

$("div.__button_image").click(function () {

    /** change button look to 'clicked' */
    $(this).addClass("__button_image_clicked");

    /** get the id of the current button */
    b_id = $(this).attr('id');

    /** unbind both vote buttons for *no* interaction */
    $("div.__button_image").unbind('click');
    $("div.__button_image").unbind('mouseover');
    $("div.__button_image").unbind('mouseout');

    /**
     * wire the .each function to iterate the classes 
     * so we can change the look of the one that was 
     * not clicked.
    */
    $('div.__button_image').each(function() {
      button_id = $(this).attr('id');
      if(button_id!=b_id) {
         $('#'+button_id).removeClass("__button_image");
         $('#'+button_id).addClass("__button_image_gray");  

    }
});

jQuery.get('/do/request?id='+b_id); 
$(this).parent().css('cursor', 'default');
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem?  The only thing I can see that you're missing is

```
$("div.__button_image").unbind('click');
```

This will remove the 'click' handler (setting it back to the default).

Comment: Thanks for the unbind advice, I took it a step further and added:
 
.unbind('click');
.unbind('mouseover');
.unbind('mouseout');

To totally disable button interaction, once the user has clicked one of the two buttons.

Comment: You could just use .unbind() (without any params) to unbind all bound events.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your click() handler to this:

```
$("div.__button_image").click(function () { 
    $(this).removeClass("__button_image_hover");
    $(this).addClass("__button_image_clicked");

    /*
     * Add look class to all buttons, then remove it from this one
     */
    $("div.__button_image").addClass("look");
    $(this).removeClass("look");

    /*
     * Remove click handler from all buttons
     */
    $("div.__button_image").unbind('click');

    jQuery.get('/do/request');        
});
```

Comment: Also good advice, I used removeClass("look") on the base class of the element (instead the changed class name).

Answer (score 1):

This always works for me (also changes the opacity to 80% and changes the cursor to wait)

```
$("#buttonDivId").css({opacity: 0.8, cursor: "wait"}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery UI you can use the disable method.

```
$("selector").button("disable");
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/button/